# Email attachment not saving correctly

Tags: powershell, csv, outlook, rename

Every morning I have an email that automatically generates, and withing the email is a CSV attachment. This is what I have so far:

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
# Below: 6 is the default for inbox, so this saves the user from having to
# select the inbox folder. Change if emails w/ attatchements are going to a
# different folder
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$filepath = "I:\PowerShell"
$folder.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
        $filename = $_.filename
        if ($filename.Contains("example.csv")) {
            $_.SaveAsFile((Join-Path $filepath $filename))
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath '.\example.csv' -NewName "Server.csv" -Force
        }                     
    }
}
```

When I run this the first time, it successfully grabs the attachment from the email, saves the attachment to the designated folder, and renames it to "Server.csv". However, when I run this a second time, it will grab the attachment and save it, however it will not rename/overwrite it as "Server.csv", so it will only save it as example.csv. It will sometimes throw an error saying

> Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists

However, I have `-Force` there, so I'm not sure why that is happening.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Force` allows you to rename a file that is hidden or read-only. It does not allow you to rename a file to replace an existing file. Check if the destination file already exists, and remove it if it does. Then save the attachment directly with the desired filename.

```
$outfile = Join-Path $filepath 'Server.csv'
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $outfile) {
    Remove-Item $outfile -Force
}
$_.SaveAsFile($outfile)
```